# How to dynamically read the value of my theme defined in the code?

Tags: android

layout：

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:text="A" 
        android:textSize="?normal_font_size" 
         />
```

attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="normal_font_size" format="dimension" />
</resources>
```

themes.xml :

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="@android :style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="normal_font_size">15px</item>
    </style>
```

**How to dynamically read the value of my theme defined in the code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `attrs.xml`, create a group of the values that you would like to read, you can even add a custom one

```
<declare-styleable name="MyAttrs">
        <attr name="android:textSize"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

In your code, you'll be able to access this value via a [`TypedArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html)

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(context.getTheme(), R.styleable.MyAttrs);
int textSize = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MyAttrs_android_textSize, DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
a.recycle();
```